# how to get custom item from ListView with row which has multiple items in android

Tags: android, listview

i would like to get custom item when a ListView row is cliked .i have a lot of items on one row , when i press on ListView row  i get all items of that row where i need one of them instead. please help me to get custom item

my  code :

```
        ....
     if (userList.size() != 0) {
        //Set the User Array list in ListView
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), userList,          R.layout.tab_0_requests_list_adapter_view,
                          new String[]{"full_name", "school", "level", "driver_fullname", "driverphone_number","plate_no","year"},
                new int[]{ R.id.names, R.id.School, R.id.SchoolLevel,     R.id.drivername, R.id.driverphone, R.id.busplateno, R.id.agenumber});

           myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    ....

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position,
                                long id) {
    String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     });
       return v;
}
```

Comment: Your listview's every single  Row contain more than one view? Tell me about your single row layout..

Comment: listItem.getChildAt(random.nextInt(listItem.getChildCount())

Comment: @ShivamSharma, not every single row contains more than two items from single row layout, as you see in code my single row layout is `tab_0_requests_list_adapter_view`

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind to a specific part, (e.g. a TextView), within your ListView item you should use a custom layout. The ViewHolder pattern will help you with this as you can bind click events on the individual views. [This example](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As i already stored mixed data in ArrayList hashmap String , i retrieved custom data from Arraylist Hasmap string as follows :

i replaced these lines :

```
          String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

With :

```
              HashMap<String, String> hashmap= userList.get(position);
                String string= hashmap.get("level");
                  .....
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), string,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```